# Getting different behavior between regex results on Windows vs Linux

Tags: python, regex, nose

I am running the following regex to extract the values before and after the `@` character in a string.

```
re.search(r'\S+ @ \S+(?=\n)', output).group().split(' @ ')
```

A sample string looks like such:

```
1
1.1
2.2
2.2.2
20 @ 0xffffffff
SUCCESS
```

I have tested this in the Python console on both environments and it works as I intend it to.

The issue I am running into is when I run my nose tests on Windows, I am getting an `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'` error on that line. This however does not happen when running the nose tests on Linux.

Comment: You should check if there is a match before accessing the `.group()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an issue because you have `\n` as a newline. In Windows, you need to specify `\r\n`. Thus, to support both Windows and Linux environments, use

```
r'\S+ @ \S+(?=\r?\n)'
```

Also, you should check if there is a match before accessing the `.group()`.